# Tell users how to sort an array, but not sorting for them. [js]

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array `[1, 10, 500, 25, 34]`.

Instead of using `array.sort((a, b) => a - b)` to make it look like `[1, 10, 25, 34, 500]`, I want to **tell the users how to sort it**, like displaying `[1, 2, 5, 3, 4]`.

I have searched many articles online, but they only show me **how to display an correctly-sorted array for me** but not **telling users how to sort an array**.

Comment: Map the array to `[[1, 1], [2, 10], [3, 500], [4, 25], [5, 34]]`, sort it by the second element and map the sorted array to the first element.

Comment: Please edit your question and add in your code segment, and then explain at what point in your code you aren't getting the result you expect.

Comment: @jabaa your algorithm will display `[1,2,4,5,3]`, not the wanted `[1,2,5,3,4]` in the question

Comment: @מתניהאופן Yes, you're right. Last step is to iterate `[1,2,4,5,3]` and write the number 1-5 into a new array according to the position.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Map the array to `[[0, 1], [1, 10], [2, 500], [3, 25], [4, 34]]`,
2. sort it by the second element,
3. iterate the sorted array and write the numbers 1-5 into a new array according to the position in the first array element.

```js
const arr = [1, 10, 500, 25, 34];

const result = arr.map((el, idx) => ([idx, el]))
                  .sort(([,lhs], [,rhs]) => lhs - rhs)
                  .reduce((acc, [el], idx) => (acc[el] = idx + 1, acc), []);
                  
console.log(result);
```